# Timer.periodic callback parameter type

Tags: dart

I'm trying to learn Dart, and run into a problem with a periodic timer like below.

```dart
void changeImage(){
  imgUrl = images.elementAt(count++);
}

startPeriodic(sec){
  return new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds:sec), changeImage);
}
```

The editor says: The argument type 'changeImage' cannot be assigned to the parameter type '(Timer) → void'

Any suggestion from you Dart-maestros out there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Timer API](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/Timer.html#periodic), the callback receives a parameter of type `Timer`, so your callback method should look like this:

```dart
void changeImage(Timer t){
  imgUrl = images.elementAt(count++);
}
```

This is different from just using `new Timer()`, which takes a callback without parameters. The reason is so you can cancel the Timer in your callback method if it is no longer required.